# catch server response code

Tags: java, api, sms, response

I am trying to send a SMS from my Java web application using the API provided on [this site](http://ubaid.tk/).

I am not able to receive the response code as its mentioned on its tutorial, which can be found  [here](http://ubaid.tk/api-usage/). I am using the Java version of the code for my project. Can anyone provide the solution?

Response codes are as below:

```
 1 : SMS sent  
-1 : Server Error  
-2 : Invalid Username  
-3 : Invalid message text  
-4 : Login Failed  
-5 : IP Blocked
```

The code is as below:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class SmsSender
{
  //Replace your way2sms username and password below
  static final String _userName = "your way2sms username";
  static final String _password = "your way2sms password";
  static final String _url = "http://ubaid.tk/sms/sms.aspx";
  static final String charset = "UTF-8";

  //to build the query string that will send a message
  private static String buildRequestString(String targetPhoneNo, String message) throws   
  UnsupportedEncodingException
  {
    String [] params = new String [5];
    params[0] = _userName;
    params[1] = _password;
    params[2] = message;
    params[3] = targetPhoneNo;
    params[4] = "way2sms";

    String query = String.format("uid=%s&pwd=%s&msg=%s&phone=%s&provider=%s",
    URLEncoder.encode(params[0],charset),
    URLEncoder.encode(params[1],charset),
    URLEncoder.encode(params[2],charset),
    URLEncoder.encode(params[3],charset),
    URLEncoder.encode(params[4],charset)
    );
    return query;
  }

  public static void sendMessage(String reciever, String message) throws Exception
  {
    //To establish the connection and perform the post request
    URLConnection connection = new URL(_url + "?" +  
    buildRequestString(reciever,message)).openConnection();
    connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", charset);

    //This automatically fires the request and we can use it to determine the response status
    InputStream response = connection.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response));
    System.out.println(br.readLine());
  }

  public static void main(String [] args)
  throws Exception
  {
    String testPhoneNo = "9876543210";
    String testMessage = "Sending Messages From java is not too hard";

    sendMessage(testPhoneNo,testMessage);
  }
}
```

Comment: *I am not able to receive the response code*... what does that mean? Do you get an exception? Are you finding that your `println` is not printing anything?

Comment: Also, I admire your patience to use an API written by someone who thinks they can force people to "like" their API by floating a message in front of their web page for 45s. Amazing.

Comment: @DuncanJones.. it is not printing anything..

Comment: It can print empty string, for me it printed "-2". Use `System.out.println("Return code: "+br.readLine());`

Comment: @ajozwik did u tried the same code or you changed it a bit?

Comment: I just copied code and run in eclipse. Without changes. Maybe you have problem with firewall/network?

Comment: @ajozwik can u send me that project as a zip file? pls its very urgent

Comment: Please use [SMS.zip](http://kapitanat.pl/~anjo/SMS.zip)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
InputStream response = connection.getInputStream();
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response));
String responseString = br.readLine();
Integer responseInt = Integer.valueOf(responseString).intValue();
switch(responseInt)
{
  case 1 : //SMS sent
  break;
  case -1 : // Server error
  break;
.
.  // put check conditions similarly
.
}
```